# Link practice without "/" in the beginning of href

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I am using this rewrite code to be able to link like this `http://page.com/subpage` but still be working with html files like so `http://page.com/subpage.html` (all html files are located in the root folder).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

**Would it be good practise to have a menu like this (without the "/" on the subpages)?**

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="subpage-1">Subpage 1</a>
<a href="subpage-2">Subpage 2</a>
<a href="subpage-3">Subpage 3</a>
```

If it's OK to link without "/" what is the best way to link the "home" link?

This is what I am planing to go with as menu (please give me reasons why not to if you have nay):

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="subpage-1">Subpage 1</a>
<a href="subpage-2">Subpage 2</a>
<a href="subpage-3">Subpage 3</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221100/is-this-good-link-practice ?

Comment: allmoast the same question, but not quite (I asked that question...). Note that I am not using the "/" on the subpages.

Comment: the reason for why i want to do this is beceause I want to be able to play with the site on a subfolder...

Comment: A better approach might be to play with the site on a *subdomain* instead of a subfolder. So `http://test.example.com/subpage` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practise to use `subpage-1` urls exactly becouse of redirections you might implement later on. If you insist on working in a folder, you can use `./subpage-1` and `./` for the home link.

Comment: Thanks Tony, can you give an example of a redirection that would be complicated in the future using this tecnique? I cant see the problem :S

Comment: Well, as many more I use SEF urls (search engine friendly), so my configuration looks something like this: url like `/news/read/1` redirects to `/news.php?action=read&id=1`. What about loading images now? `/img/something.jpg` will get from root, but `img/something.jpg` will search in `/news/read/1` directory, which does not exist. So how would you tell it to see `img/a.jpg` as `/folder/img/a.jpg` and not as `/folder/news/read/1/img/a.jpg`? But still, if you are absolutely sure you are not going to mess with subfolders, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I will never use deep-linking on these websites... (what if you came up with a good idea to rename news to "news-about-html". then you would have to do some 301 redirects and you would lose some linkjuice by doing that. It's good to be flexible... Also I think it looks better as well to only have one level all the time.) images will be loaded from a subdomain.

Comment: But it's a very important note you got there... Maybe there will be problem with cacheing favoicon, js and CSS if you deside not to  "absolute link" those...

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally make everything absolute in this kind of situation (providing that you reasonably can), just because the potential for confusion on your part is **far** too high. If you make things relative, you will get one wrong, guaranteed.

If your project is 30+ pages, then I'd definitely have a re-think on that, and if you're using some kind of scripting language (PHP, ASP, etc) then you should make use of that to make your job easier.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I don't think I will be able to link it wrong. I will never use any sub/sub/subfolders. All files will be in the same root folder. I will only have a few html pages, maybe 5-15 pages... Still think its a bad idea to go without the "/"?

Comment: Should be OK, just bear in mind that if you change one it has to change in all those files :)

Comment: Thanks Joe, just to me 100% finished with this question. Would you say that my last example would be OK? ("./" in the home and nothing on the subpages...)

Comment: Yep. I'd possibly not make "./" a link (just leave it as `Home` instead of `<a href="./">Home</a>`, or at worst `<a>Home</a>`

Comment: Anchors without `href` do not act like links. Just a note :)

Comment: That's kind of the point :P Why would you link back to the page you're already on, unless it's the homepage? :)

Answer (score 0):

I always keep the `/` in front of any hrefs like this.

---

Using relative paths is a bad habit to begin with and a recipe for disaster later on. If you start with relative urls and find you need them later on, it'll be a big pain to add. Having one extra character per link isn't the end of the world.

Say I have a site with these 2 pages:

```
/home/ryan/example.com/index.html
/home/ryan/example.com/public.html
```

And the html content of each was the same:

*index.html* & *public.html*

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/public">Public</a>
```

Now if I want to add a new file, `/home/ryan/example.com/special/secret.html` I can re-use that existing code, and even add in a new link while still making the same code work for all 3 pages:

*all html pages*

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/public">Public</a>
<a href="/special/surprise">Surprise</a>
```

Consider maintenance down the road and think of your future lazy self. Being able to re-use code is the whole point; you don't want to add/edit/delete slightly different links from up to 15 places, even 2 places is too much!